# i want the input box and the search button combine? why the div is applicable of the margin i want that search from the top 40px below

Tags: html, css

i want to

```css
.k1 {
 width: 760px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: 40px;
}
.k2 {
 width: 670px;
 height: 30px;
}
.k3 {
 width: 75px;
 height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="k1">
  <input type="text" class="k2"></input>
  <button value="search" class="k3" ></button>
</div>
```

i want the input box and button combine and 40px from the top 
why div is varied with the margin
the elements in the div is some where and div  block is some where

the elemets inside the div vary with the div margin if div margin-top is 40 px the tags inside the is div is with  margin-top with some margin from the top of the document

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffcc;
  }
.k1 {
  margin-top: 40px; 
  height: 30px;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
.k2 {
  display: block; 
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 75px);
  height: 100%;
}
.k3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="k1">
  <input type="text" class="k2">
  <button value="search" class="k3">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i want that div is 40px down from the top

Comment: It is 40px down from the top, because of: `margin-top: 40px;`

Comment: what is the meaning of this   box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: `box-sizing` specify whether elements should have padding and border included in the element's total width and height or not. [more information about](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: if i want i box size and the button changes according to the size of the screen what is the property is need?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nk.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="kowshik"> 
            <p class="banu">
<img src="images/ic1.png" class="bhanu" >
<img src="images/ic2.png" class="bhanu" >
<img src="images/ic3.png" class="bhanu"  >
<img src="images/ic4.png" class="bhanu" >
            </p>
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="k">
        <div class="k1">
            <input type="text" class="k2"/>
          <button value="search" class="k3" />
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>   
</html>

Comment: *
{
    margin:0;
    border: 0;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.kowshik
{
    background-color: rgb(23,125,210);
    
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
}
.banu
{
     float: right;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 20px;
    display: inline;
}
.bhanu{
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
}
.k{
    width: 25%;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
}
.k1{  margin-top: 40px;width: 500px;height: 30px; overflow: hidden;}
.k2 {display: block;float: left;width: 425px; height: 30px;}
.k3 { display: block; float: left; width: 75px;height: 30px;}

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer. No the div is 100% width of the site.

Comment: above is my code if i give the margin-top:40px; it varies with header div

Answer (score 0):

Please explain more on the issue. If you want to align both input and button from the top and want to add margin to a particular element(input or button). In that case, you have to add vertical-align:top to .k2 or .k3

```
.k1{
    width:760px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:40px;
}
.k2{
    width:670px;
    height:30px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.k3{
    width:75px;
    height:30px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Ok, add vertical-align:top; to .k2 or .k3  as shown in above code it will resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The first input does not need a closing tag. It should be:

```
<input type="text" class="k2" />
```

The button and inputs have `display: inline-block` (which takes margin to left) by default. Code will be:

```
.k2{
    width:670px;
    height:30px;
    float: left
}
.k3{
    width:75px;
    height:30px;
    float: left
}
```

So either use float: left; to both element and the clearfix class to the parent (if you are using Bootstrap), otherwise you will have to use height or clear property for the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the button as input and include its type in it.

```css
.k1{
    width:760px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:40px;
}
.k2{
width:670px;
height:30px;
}
.k3{
    width:75px;
    height:35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="k1">
    <input type="text" class="k2"></input>
    <input type="button" value="search" class="k3"></input>
</div>
```